# Routing problem with Kohana 3.1.2

Tags: php, internationalization, routes, kohana, lang

My Kohana route wont work correctly

The route:

```
    Route::set('admin', '((<lang>/)admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))',
    array( 
        'lang' => '(de|en)',
        'id'     => '.+' 
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'lang'              => 'de',
        'controller'    => 'dashboard',
        'action'        => 'index',
        'directory'     => 'admin',
  ));
```

with the url "en/admin"

```
Request::current()->param( 'lang' );
```

returns "de" and not "en"

when i dont set the url default for "lang" the request returns "en-us", i didn't set i18n::lang()

thx for Help =)

Comment: may be you have changes in system classes like Request or Route? Like this: http://www.kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=example_of_a_multi-language_website

Answer (score 1):

`I18n::lang()` is called in bootstrap, setting the default to `en-us`.

Your request is returning "de" because it's the default you've set, you should try defining the route pattern like this:

```
'((<lang>)(/)admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))'
```

Comment: thank you for the answer - but still same problem. with previous version of kohana the route worked correctly. :(